# drag and drop svg element to other svg container

Tags: angular, svg, drag-and-drop

Is it possible to drag&drop SVG element from one SVG container to another SVG container? It will be between different angular components. I have SVGs setup like this:

```
<svg>
    <g><!-- some elements --></g>
</svg>
<svg> -destinatin container
</svg>
```